# How to get Gradle jar task to output same archive that is generated by bootJar

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jar, build.gradle, executable-jar

I have a Gradle based SpringBoot `2.7.9` application and when I execute `./gradlew jar` it produces:

```
/Users/user/git/repo/build/libs/repo-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar
```

Which is not executable.

I really want the output of `jar` to be same as what is generated when `bootJar` is executed.

Running `gradlew bootJar`, `repo-0.11.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` is generated and it is executable.

I need to continue using `./gradlew jar`.

```
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot")
}

val gitBuildURL: String by project
val gitBranchName: String by project
val gitCommit: String by project

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.7.9")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.7.9")
    implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.20.0")
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.7.9")
}

tasks.getByName<Jar>("jar") {
    // what can I do here to make the output be the output of bootJar?
}

publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("springLib") {
            from(components["java"])
            versionMapping {
                usage("java-api") {
                    fromResolutionOf("runtimeClasspath")
                }
                usage("java-runtime") {
                    fromResolutionResult()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    publish {
        defaults{
            publications("springLib")
            setProperties(mapOf(
                "git.build.url" to gitBuildURL,
                "git.branch.name" to gitBranchName,
                "git.commit.id" to gitCommit
            ))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `jar` task and `bootJar` task are different where the former is created by Gradle through the `java` plugin and the latter by Spring Boot through the Spring Boot Plugin. What is your use case as to why you need `jar` to be the output of `bootJar`?

Comment: I have another project which builds a Docker image using a Docker Gradle plugin for the application in question, when the Docker creation project runs `build` both `jar` and `bootJar` are executed but only the output of `jar` gets consumed by the Docker Gradle plugin